# ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe") when using asyncio with subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
def run_async(spawn_coro, timeout):
    async def _read_print_line(process):
        line = await process.stdout.readline()
        line = line.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
        sys.stdout.write(line)

    process = await spawn_coro
    try:
        while not process.stdout.at_eof():
            # We should cancel if no output has been received for a certain timeout
            await asyncio.wait_for(_read_print_line(process), timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Timed out executing "{}".  No output received for {} seconds'.format(cmd, timeout))
        process.kill()
    await process.wait()

processes = [asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) for cmd in cmds]

loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()   # This is windows
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
all_jobs = asyncio.gather(
    *(run_async(process, timeout) for process in processes)
)
loop.run_until_complete(all_jobs)
loop.close()
```

When the process exits, I get a bunch of error output like this:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001CD9B582AF8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 93, in __del__
    warnings.warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning,
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 57, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ at 0x000001CD9B571DC8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    warnings.warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning,
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 78, in __repr__
    info.append(f'stdout={stdout.pipe}')
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 57, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\Users\divis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
```

If I remove the `loop.close()`, then instead of errors the process just hangs.  I'm properly awaiting every subprocess before I close the loop, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Try adding `process.stdout.close()` and `process.stderr.close()` at the end of `run_async`.

Comment: `close()` is not a method of `StreamReader`.  Also, I would expect that to be handled internally by the runtime?

Comment: Hmm if I add `await process.stdout.read()` to the end, maybe that fixes it.  Doing some more testing

Comment: Doing that makes it not print the error, but it also doesn't kill the process, even though I've written `process.terminate()`.  The process seems to just keep running until it's done.

Comment: *Also, I would expect that to be handled internally by the runtime?* - not really, in Python you are very much expected to explicitly close the external resources you acquire. (This is sometimes handled by the `with` statement, but it's still explicit.) Judging by the stack trace, it seems that Python detects that the stream was not closed and tries to close it by the time it's already too late. That that caused an exception is arguably a bug in the runtime, but closing the stream explicitly is still a good workaround, if it works.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately now it seems like terminate() just...  isn't doing anything.  The whole reason for this code is to try to detect deadlocked processes and kill them, so terminate needs to work.  Maybe it's better to open a separate question for that?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a separate (though possibly related) issue. A _runnable_ minimal example that reproduces the issue would likely help with getting the question answered.

Comment: I found this ticket as I'm basically trying to do exactly the same thing. I'm only even attempting to use asyncio so that I can do some non blocking IO on a process I've started to see if I should kill it after x amount of seconds of inactivity (on Windows). @ZacharyTurner did you ask about terminate not working anywhere?

Comment: Yea terminate not working is because i was using shell=True, so terminate() was killing the shell process, but not the one under it.

Comment: I had tried with `create_subprocess_exec` and terminate wasn't killing the subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I just had the same problem, and I was able to solve it like this:

```
try:
    process = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(cmd)
    ...
    await process.wait()
finally:
    process._transport.close()
```

Taking a look at the code, this seems to close the piped file handles from the child process. I don't know why asyncio doesn't expose this as part of the returned Process object.